# Extracting XML data in Python: Data prints, but the sum is not being returned

Tags: python, xml, sum

My code compiles and returns the data in the output.  I asked for the sum of the numbers to get printed, and the program won't print it.  Is something wrong with my sum statement? Should I separate the print statements?

Here is what I have written:

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

serviceurl = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
while True:
    url = serviceurl + urllib.urlencode({'sensor':'false', 'address': 'address'})
    print ('Retrieving', url)
    uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
    data = uh.read()
    print ('Retrieved',len(data),'characters')
    print (data)
    tree = ET.fromstring(data)
    results = tree.findall('.//count')
print (results, sum(results))
```

**This shows what the XML data looks like:**

```
<comment>
  <name>Matthias</name>
  <count>97</count>
</comment>
```

Comment: You can't sum strings (pass numbers to sum, not strings).  By the way, you don't say what happens when you run the program, which is not as helpful to readers of your question as you could be -- this makes a big difference!

Comment: What version?

You're using print as in Python 3 and urllib.urlencode as in Python 2.

Comment: I have both Pythons installed.  When the programs runs, it compiles and returns the data from the URL and the number of characters in the file.  Nothing else is printed.

Comment: Should I have something like:  count = ["comment"][0]["count"]

Comment: count = tree["comment"][0]["count"]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to parse the number from the count tag and convert it to an int object in order to do the summation.

If there's multiple counts, you can pull them into a list and then iterate through the list to get the sum.

For example:

```
totcomm = 0    # set initial sum value to zero
counts = tree.findall('comments/comment')  # create list of comments
for item in counts:                        # iterate through list 
   x = item.find('count').text             # pass count content to x
   totcomm = tot + int(x)                  # add integer of x to total
print totcomm
```

I'd also restructure the program, so that you're not repeatedly going back to the URL (While True), but just making one call and passing all that data to your 'data' variable. In this case, you just need:

```
url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_42.xml'
print 'Retrieving', url
```

and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
print(results, sum([float(x) for x in results]))
```

You have to convert `string` to something summable like `int` or `float`.

Comment: Thank you all for your inputs.  They were very helpful for me to understand my mistakes.

Answer (score 0):

## I really appreciate this site your advice is overwhelming - thanks to all of #you! Here is my suggestion to the question -at-hand...

```
import urllib
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

url = raw_input('Enter location: ')
if len(url) == 0:
   url = 'http://python-data.dr-chuck.net/comments_189090.xml'    
uh = urllib.urlopen(url)
data = uh.read()
tree = ET.fromstring(data)
count = 0
totalcounts = 0                            # set initial sum value to zero
counts = tree.findall('comments/comment')  # create list of comments
for item in counts:                        # iterate through list 
   x = item.find('count').text             # pass count content to x
   totalcounts = totalcounts + int(x)      # add integer of x to total
   count = count + 1
print count   
print totalcounts
```